# How to clickable for markers in google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using google map and I set markers to my map like this:

```
var marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(item.lat)!, longitude: Double(item.lon)!))


 marker.map = mapview
```

now,I would like to detect when user click on these markers.

How can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should set your `mapview` delegate to `self` `UIViewController` in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.mapview.delegate = self
```

your `UIViewController` should

```
extension ViewControllerClass: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    //class code

    @objc(mapView:didTapMarker:) func mapView(_: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        //do something
        return true
    }
}
```

maybe this method can be implemented some other way already, but `Xcode` forced me to make it this way while migrating from `Swift 2` to `Swift 3`

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 3**

You can implement `GMSMapViewDelegate`something like this:

```
extension YourViewConytoller: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print ("MarkerTapped Locations: \(marker.position.latitude), \(marker.position.longitude)")
        return true
    }
}
```